# Toolbar not showing in API < 21

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to make 2 kinds of activities: with toolbar (login) and others with toolbar.

**values/themes.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="My.Login" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="My.Login.ScrollView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

My manifest has `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

On main activity I use root element:`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"`

On login activity I use in root element `app:theme="@style/My.Login"
style="@style/My.Login.ScrollView"`

All activity classes extends `AppCompatActivity`.

When I am running app in API >= 21 it's ok, but in API<21 I have an empty space on the toolbar's place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use that :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

in your activity's onCreate() method to hide ActionBar.
By the way, you have to hide StatusBar:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
} else {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

You can find [here](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) about that.

Comment: When I try to hide actionBar its working (with getSupportActionBar method).
But the base problem is empty space in main activity on the toolbar's place.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. For my case, I had to import-

```
import.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

in my Activity. After importing the error was solved.